# Database design, multiple types of customers in the same table

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database-design, architecture, e-commerce

Business scenario:

- Customers can login to an online e-Commerce app, using their e-mail addresses as their logins.
- We have a CRM app that depends on the same database. Employees use the CRM app to add non-online customers, and e-mail is NOT required field here.

Technically:
There is nothing "naturally" making a PK in Customer table. Regardless, I always use an artificial PK even if there is no natural one. I'm worried that this will eventually lead to problems in searching, integrity, etc. I can't determine exactly what problems will come up, though.

I think developers won't expect the e-mail column to allow null, and they will create programs ignoring this situation.

Remember that the whole system, and most of the database will depend on customer data, if something goes wrong in the customer table, it will probably be inherited by the other tables.

**The existence of two types of customers fires exceptions in my brain, but I can't figure out the exception's message. What do you think?  Is it better to find some way out now? Or you think, it is ok, leave it like this till something goes wrong, because it is not likely to cause a problem, Remember that the problem is not a bug by neccissary, it can be maintainability or development complications ?**

Thanks

Comment: What is the issue? Why can't you use a simple surrogate key (auto-incrementing) as a PK?

Comment: that what I mean by artificial PK

Comment: Is the CRM a packaged solution or in-house development?

Comment: Which one is it? Is it a packaged solution, or is it developed in-house? Or, are you saying that the company you work for has modified a packaged solution?

Comment: @Costa: If it's a purchased package I'd never, ever try to modify the internal tables nor trying to directly insert data into those tables. Create a 'satellite' system managing your extended requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a specific reason to put these data together in the same table? Do CRM "customers" and e-commerce customers share many other tables in this database?

Honestly, I would not put e-commerce customers in this database. Although you can create views to easily separate e-commerce and CRM data, this seems totally unnecessary to me. Furthermore, you haven't described any particular reason why e-commerce and CRM data need to live in the same database. Maybe there's a reason you didn't include in the question, but this already smells if you ask me.

From the information you've included here, I don't think you're losing anything significant by creating a separate database and table for the e-commerce customers. Keep unrelated data separate.

**Edit:**

To make this extra clear: if your e-commerce customers **do not share** a lot of data with the CRM customers, **create new customer tables**. If they **do share** a lot of data, then one null column is likely not the end of the world.

Comment: The systems are there already, and I did not participate in this design.

So you agree with me, it will cause some troubles someday, and I must do something, or you will leave it like this till something actually goes wrong.

Comment: Will the new e-commerce customers share a lot of data with the CRM customers? You didn't include details about this in your original question. **If the answer is yes**, then I think it's okay to put the e-commerce customers in the same table -- the null e-mail column isn't the end of the world. **If the answer is no**, then you need to think about creating a separate e-commerce database and customer tables.

Comment: e-commerce customer email is Required in e-Commerece app, however CRM customer email is not required for the CRM app, and yes the two apps shares almost everything.  

So I got both in the same table, I will have a design that does not really force integrity for e-Commerce app....Agree?

Comment: That's true, but there are a lot of other ways to enforce data integrity that don't include table-level designs. You could write a constraint that checks the customer type, and then requires the e-mail address if the customer is an e-commerce customer, for instance.

Comment: Now you talk.....thanks, however I am sorry I was not clear, I am trying to determine whether I over estimate the design issue, through everyone answers.  So I will ask you a direct question: Do you think it does not need all of that thinking?

Comment: Yes, I think you're over-estimating the design issue. You can maintain your data integrity in other ways without having to re-create the entire database or create new tables. Enforce, communicate, and document the requirements thoroughly, and you'll be fine.

Comment: I agree with @jwiscarson, maintaining a Customer type, and managing authentication based on that type is better way; without thinking of too much about the design issue.